# Is there a way to extend background color of unordered list items to go behind bullets?

Tags: css

I have an unordered list and I want to have the list items have alternating background colors.  I'm using bullets in the list.  Is there a way to extend the background of the color horizontally to get under the bullet?

Margin and padding just push the bullet away.

[image: list]
<sub>(source: [mbira.me](http://www.mbira.me/images/ul_li.jpg))</sub>

Comment: hmmm...tried to add a screenshot.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `list-style-position: inside`.

Comment: cool-I haven't heard of that one...going to go read up on it now.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks Max! CSS is great, and you are great!  I hope that I can contribute answers to people soon!

Comment: Wow. Learn something new each day. I hadn't heard of that before either.

Comment: can I ask a followup-how would I then keep the indention of the text on a text wrap then (IE so text doesn't end up below the bullet)?

Comment: ah-Google is my friend.  http://groups.google.com/group/web-authoring/browse_thread/thread/b5272da8c7714c72?pli=1