# more unordered list padding/margin cross-browser craziness

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I just received this awesome help:
[Is there a way to extend background color of unordered list items to go behind bullets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144010/is-there-a-way-to-extend-background-color-of-unordered-list-items-to-go-behind-bu)

and then I was dealing with the text-indent property to again line up the wrapped text in this unordered list, but lo and behold it looks like IE and FF are handling the padding differently enough to really mess with the layout.  Any solution?

Firefox (good)

[image: FF Good]
<sub>(source: [mbira.me](http://mbira.me/images/ff_good.jpg))</sub>

IE (bad)
[image]
<sub>(source: [mbira.me](http://mbira.me/images/ie_bad.jpg))</sub>

The css for the list:

```
.registerbox ul{

}

.registerbox ul li.light{
list-style-type:disc;
list-style-position:inside;
margin:2px 0px 2px -20px;
padding:2px 30px;
background-color:#FFFFB0;
text-indent:-12px;
}
.registerbox ul li.dark{
list-style-type:disc;
list-style-position:inside;
margin:2px 0px 2px -20px;
padding:0px 30px;
text-indent:-12px;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post some of your html/css. Also, what version of IE? You may find this helpful if you're dealing with IE6/7 *cringes* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

Comment: CSS posted this is in IE 7 and 8.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do it without either (A) specifying a separate stylesheet for IE and setting a different indent there or (B) using no bullets.

Comment: cool.  Thanks for trying.  I guess this is a case where an image would be good.

Comment: yeah-to followup-I just made a png of the bullet and got rid of the default bullet.  Works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this, I ended up making a png of the bullet and got rid of the default bullets.